# (Git) How can I set parameters using alias

Tags: git

I ofter use the below command

```
$git commit -am "something message"
```

After setting alias, unfortunately that'd not work well.

.gitconfig file is

```
[alias]
    am = "!f(){ git commit -am \"$1\";};f"
```

And then I tried,

```
$ git am "modified something logic"
```

something error occurred.

```
fatal: could not open 'filepath//modified something logic: No such file or directory
```

What is wrong to set alias??

Thanks.

Comment: you don't need to set an alias to use the options -a and -m. Remove the alias from your configuration file and then your command `git commit -am "something message"` should work just fine

Comment: "After setting alias, unfortunately that'd not work well." what output did you get?

Comment: Also `git commit -am` isn't something you should need an alias for. It's better to stage necessary files manually and then commit them, preferably using git commit rather than `git commit -m`

Comment: I want to use short cut using alias to reduce typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`am` is a built in command :

```
$ git help am

NAME
   git-am - Apply a series of patches from a mailbox
```

Choose another name for your alias (and check it isn't already taken ...)

Comment: You are definitely right!! I didn't know that am command!!
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

As LeGEC advised me, I changed alias to coam instead am.

```
$ git config --global alias.coam '!f(){ git commit -am "$1";};f'
```

After that, I can use the below command that is equal to **$ git commit -am "something message"**

```
$ git coam "something message"
```